# Not able to change the format of date in datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am using the below datepicker but I am not able to change the format of the date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#mdateupto', function () {
    $("#mdateupto").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat","yyyy-mm-dd");
    $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" );
  });
});
```

Please help,

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want the date to come in yyyy-mm-dd format but it is coming in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2):

you should define your dateFormat option in your datepicker() initialisation or you can set it after it has been initialised following should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#mdateupto', function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    }).datepicker( "show" );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, it is not working. I am still getting date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Sam, actually I am using bootstrap with jquery. So I am getting bootstrap datepicker. Also I do an ajax call of a page in which datepicker id is defined. In the main page where ajax page gets in has your datepicker javascript code. Please see if you can help me resolve this issue.